# Manga about some creepy detective guy that can bring dead to life to ask them questions?

Tags: story-identification, manga

There are demon/monster things that will make deals with humans for which the humans have to fill like a quota.

This popular high school kid makes a deal and has to kill people using his phone and calling people and if they answer they die.

There's a detective guy with powers to bring the dead to life to ask a few questions, but they can only answer very simple questions. He pretends to be a science teacher at the school and asks the popular kid's friend to help him find out who made the deal with the demon thing.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Was it colour or black-and-white?